# How to make random number generator not generate the same number twice

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

I'm fairly new to programming and I've been working on a project that finds four random divs and adds a class to them -- my only problem is that because my random generator has been generating the same number frequently, the program usually does not append the class to FOUR random divs but most likely three or even two. So my question is, how, if possible would I set my program to only generate four DIFFERENT numbers.
I've heard of the Fisher Yates attempt, but I did not get it fully.
Here is my JS:

```
for(var i = 4; i>0; i--){
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*16)+1);
var array=new Array(); 
array[1] = "one";
array[2] = "two";
array[3] = "three";
array[4] = "four";
array[5] = "five";
array[6] = "six";
array[7] = "seven";
array[8] = "eight";
array[9] = "nine";
array[10] = "ten";
array[11] = "eleven";
array[12] = "twelve";
array[13] = "thirteen";
array[14] = "fourteen";
array[15] = "fifteen";
array[16] = "sixteen";
$('#'+array[rand]).addClass('bomb');
}
```

Thanks a lot to any help!

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6274398/251311 2. Start indexing with `0`, not `1`

Comment: What problem did you have with Fisher Yates shuffle? Have you looked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array. You need to shuffle the array, then grab four elements.

Comment: just make a list of everything, shuffle the list, and take the first four. google an [].shuffle method if you don't want to write your own, but lookout for ones based on sort(); they don't actually randomize...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of comments: First of all, you should initialize you array outside of the for loop, so that it only does it once.  Also, as @zerkms pointed out, you should start your array at index 0, not 1.  To prevent repeating a number, you could simply remove the ones you have already chosen from the array.  Here is an example of how you could do this:

```
var array=new Array(); 
array[0] = "one";
array[1] = "two";
array[2] = "three";
array[3] = "four";
array[4] = "five";
array[5] = "six";
array[6] = "seven";
array[7] = "eight";
array[8] = "nine";
array[9] = "ten";
array[10] = "eleven";
array[11] = "twelve";
array[12] = "thirteen";
array[13] = "fourteen";
array[14] = "fifteen";
array[15] = "sixteen";
for(var i = 4; i>0; i--){
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*array.length));
    $('#'+array[rand]).addClass('bomb');
    array.splice(rand,1);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Edit:  I've removed the unnecessary while loop that caused an error.

Comment: Thanks @Jlennon321 , however -- your answer seems to crash JSFiddle! Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: My bad! I had an error in my code. I've edited it, and it should work now.

Comment: Thanks you are a great help! @Jlennon321

Answer (score 0):

this is example of your topic problem ( from 1 to 13 )

```
for (var i = 0, ar = []; i < 14; i++) { ar[i] = i; }
console.log( ar.sort(function () { return Math.random() - 0.5; }) );
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 6, 13, 4, 8, 9, 12, 10, 7, 11] ->> run first time
[3, 7, 4, 10, 1, 9, 11, 8, 13, 12, 2, 5, 0, 6] ->> runt second time
etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by shuffling the array first, as explained in [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15676506/1338292).

```
kfy(array);
for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    $('#' + array[i]).addClass('bomb');
}
```